# How can i find the angle between start and the most nearest 5 objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
GridGenerator gridgenerator = GetComponent<GridGenerator>();

List<float> distances = new List<float>();
List<float> rotations = new List<float>();

for (int i = 0; i < gridgenerator.allBlocks.Length; i++)
{
    distances.Add(Vector3.Distance(start.position, gridgenerator.allBlocks[i].transform.position));
}

distances.Sort();
```

Now i have a List with all the distances.

Now what i want to do is to take the most 3 nearest objects to start but that the angle between them and start is on the 90 degrees. It can be 90 or -90 or 0.

Or maybe i wrong with the angles values. What i mean is that the most 3 nearest objects and that the angle between them and start is: right left straight. Not object/s that are in diagonal from start.

Comment: You're generating a grid, if you're interested in only orthogonal relationships, don't use angles to find them, use position. `(x,y)`, `(x+1,y)`, `(x-1,y)`, and `(x,y+1)`.

Comment: @Draco18s My goal my main goal is to find the next nearest object in the grid randomly. For example to take the 3-5 nearest objects in this case cubes and from them randomly to find one as next object to move to or to call it next waypoint to move to.  But since it's a grid the player should move only right left or straight and not in diagonal.

Comment: Since it's a grid in this case cubes but can be any prefabs like spheres at any point there will be 3 or 5 or 8 objects around the player and i want to randomly find one of them to be the next waypoint.

Comment: So pick a random *direction* and then find the gridpos that matches.

Comment: @Draco18s but how do i find the possible directions ? Before i rotate the player how do i know if he can move straghit back right left or noly part of the directions ?

Comment: If you're at the edge of the grid, that direction is invalid.

Comment: Capture the 3 closest transforms where position.x = start.position.x or position.y = start.position.y, then choose one randomly